# change the value of a cell through time with the next item in column

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I would like to know if there is any way to change the value of a cell every 10 seconds. The new value would be the next cell in a column and so forth until it went through all none-blank cells.

Comment: Yes there are at least a couple of ways.

Comment: well that is helpful , do you mind giving me an idea of what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application.OnTime` Function to call a Function every 10 seconds:

```
Dim i As Integer

Function startTimer()

'Set counter to 1
i = 1
'Call Function
TimerFunction
End Function

Function TimerFunction()

'Write Current Time to Column A
Sheets("Table1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

'If counter = 10, stop Timer
If i = 10 Then

    Exit Function
End If

i = i + 1
'Call this Function with a delay of 10 seconds
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "TimerFunction"
End Function
```

So change the `If` condition to something that matches your task. Maybe this: If current column = last used column (If I understood you right)

Comment: For what reason is is `startval` declared? Also, do you know the difference between a function and a sub?

Comment: Ups, startval is useless, had this to try something out, forgot to delete it. Sub can be found when you press on Macros in the Developer tab, Functions won't be shown there. Functions can return something, Subs can't.

Comment: @gizlmeier - You are trying to change cell value in function `TimerFunction` via `Sheets("Table1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")`. This is incorrect as UDF cannot modify anything in the worksheet. UDF only returns the final result.

Comment: @Mrig could you explain what you mean exactly?